# Trying to split a sub statement over multiple lines in Excel VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a sub statement which is receiving multiple arguments from the other sub which calls it (apologies, I am quite new at this - so my terminology may not be spot on).

The number of arguments I am passing is quite a few, so it extends off my screen. For ease of reading **I would like to split the argument list over multiple lines**. I have tried to use the "Space underscore" trick like you would within the `sub`. However, when I do, VBA stops recognising the `sub` as it's own routine.

Any ideas how I can do this?

*E.g.* This works:

```
... 
End Sub ' from previous subroutine

Sub openfile(ByVal Res, ByVal Book, ByVal inp) 'there are other arguments as well, but I have shortened them for convenience here. 

....

End Sub
```

But this doesn't:

```
... 
End sub ' from previous subroutine

Sub openfile(ByVal Res, ByVal Book, _

ByVal inp) 'there are other arguments as well, but I have shortened them for convenience here. 

....

End Sub
```

Answer (score 15):

You can't have a **completely** empty line (a blank line) between the `_` and the next part of your code. Remove the extra line and you'll be fine. Basically, do this:

```
Sub openfile(ByVal Res, ByVal Book, _
ByVal inp) 'there are other arguments as well, but I have shortened them for convenience here.
```

If you really want to have an *almost* blank line, you can do this:

```
Sub openfile(ByVal Res, ByVal Book, _
 _
ByVal inp) 'there are other arguments as well, but I have shortened them for convenience here.
```

Notice that the `_` that's on its own line must have a space character in front of it; that's important.